# How can I execute a simple Jar on AWS to perform some operation on S3 buckets

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am very new to AWS environment . I am trying to understand the system. For now I created a simple jar that simply list out the buckets available in my aws S3 env.

But where can I execute the jar to get the result?.. I am where at AWS

Also I have installed `awscli` on my local machine, but once I connect with the aws env using awscli , I no longer able to access my local system, how does it work ?

How can I execute my jar from awscli client ?

I will be really grateful for your help !!

Thanks, 
Arpan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no service that runs a jar file straight from S3.

There are several options, all of them require some setup:

- EC2 instance: just start up a server, upload your jar file and run.
- Elastic Beanstalk: Create an environment, Procfile, package your jar in a zip file with the Procfile, upload and deploy
- Lambda: Write your code against their java API, create a jar file, upload (can be an s3 path, but if you update the file on s3, you have to re-upload it to lambda) and deploy

If your process runs in less than 5 minutes, an AWS Lambda is the best as you don't have to worry about servers.

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro Carrasco .. I was actually looking more no something that I can run from my local system .. like for a hadoop system (either Clouder or Hortonworks distribution) one can run his jar for any edge node..

But actually now I have solved my query .. for connecting with AWS system either S3 , DynamoDb or anything I just need to setup my aws credentials and then I can debug or run a jar local on my system that can communicate with aws system. 

And for that I dont need Lambda system , to first deploy my jar than check if it is working fine or not.